# Any special meaning in the phrase "out to the edges"?

Tags: meaning

I was watching ted lecture about cryptocurrency and the future of money.

Then the lecturer remarked as following :

> With programmable money, we decouple the need for large, trusted institutions from the architecture of the network. And this pushes innovation in money out to the edges, where it belongs. Programmable money democratizes money. And because of this, things are going to change and unfold in ways that we can't even predict.

In the second sentece of above excerpt I am little comfusing about the meaning of "out to the edges"

Any guidlines?

Comment: Away from the traditional, tried and (to a certain degree) trusted ways of dealing with the saving / transfer of money.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth any reference?

Comment: No, and therefore a 'comment' rather than an 'answer'. But it's obviously the peripheral-is-less-conventional/more-adventurous-and-risky metaphor.